# Python: stuck in indexing vowel

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, for-loop, indexing

So I am preparing for a midterm exam, and doing exercises from a pdf book, i faced this exercise:

" Write code that for a string prints the indices of all of its vowels (a, e, i, o, and u). This can be done with a for loop or a while loop. "

It's given: s = "And now for something completely different"

I coded that:

```
for j in s:
    for i in range(len(s)):
         if s[i] == "a" or s[i] =="e" or s[i] == "i" or s[i] == "o" or s[i] == "u":
              print (j[i])
```

And i get the error: 
'string index out of range'

I tried that because I used it in another exercise similar that asked for the index of a common letter between two strings, there worked, but now, I don't understand why doesn't work. I'll appreciate if you could explain me how should I look at the exercise. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need `for j in s:`. Remove it and change `print(j[i])` to `print(i)`

Comment: Oh God, i complicated myself, thank you! I probably wanted to print also the vowel itself, idk. Thank you!

Comment: You should be careful of the uppercase letters too. Something like `if letter.lower() in 'aeiou':` might be useful.

Comment: Yea, i completed that because didn't take me the 0 index of "A", now it's fine, thank you too! I did it like: ' for i in range(len(s)):
    s = s.lower()
    if s[i] == "a" or s[i] =="e" or s[i] == "i" or s[i] == "o" or s[i] == "u":
        print (i)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `s` seems to be a list of strings. Each string that you process is going to be in the `j` variable so your uses of `len(s)` and `s[...]` are indexing the list `s`, not the characters of the string `j`.  Because you were consistent in that mistake up until the last line (`print(j[i])`) it is on that line that the error is detected but the problem is actually on every other reference to `s` instead of `j`

BTW, you don't really need a set. you can just use the `in` operator on regular strings. For a small number of items, this may give sufficient performance using the basic tools that you've learned so far:

```
for j in s:
    for i in range(len(j)):
        if j[i] in "aeiou":
            print(i,j[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use a set to store the vowel, time complexity to search in a set is O(1)

```
vowel = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'}

for i, e in enumerate(s):
    if e in vowel:
        print(i)
```

Comment: use vowel as list type

Comment: @Ratnesh time complexity to search in a set is O(1)

Comment: I didn't think about that because I only learned about variables, functions, conditions, iterations, indexing, text file. Suppose set is something else. Thank you anyway!

Comment: A set object is an unordered collection of distinct hashable objects, you can have a look over the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

Comment: Well if you really want to go into time complexity than also searching in the string (or list for that matter) `'aeiou'` is `O(5)` which is basically `O(1)`. Bottom line is it's not dependant of input size. But, set is usually the preferred type for that indeed...

Comment: what about best practice? now someone may think is fine to use a list than when you have big data may get in trouble

Comment: Thanks for info @kedderrac!